# How to call a function of a class from other function file?

Tags: php, mysqli

I know thats not the best title for my question but I coulnd't come up with a better one (Suggestions are welcome)

Well, this is my situation, I have 3 files:

1) classDBConn.php - In this file is where I connect to the DB and have some functions like this:

```
class DBConn{
var $conexion;
private $querySql;
var $respuesta;
var $resultado;
function __construct() { 
    $this->conexion = @mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'dataBase');
    if(!$this->conexion){
        die('error de conexion('.mysqli_connect_errno().')'.mysqli_connect_error());    
    }
}
function checkBracketGanador($id_torneo){
    $this->querySql = "SELECT COUNT(id_ganador) FROM brackets WHERE id_torneo = '$id_torneo'";
    $this->respuesta = mysqli_query($this->conexion,$this->querySql);
    $this->resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($this->respuesta);
    return $this->resultado[0];
}
// More functions with queries
```

Note: queries and functions are fine

2)inc_conf.php - In this file is where I create the session and object DBConn. Code:

```
session_start();
include('classDBConn.php');
$functionsDBConn= new DBConn();
$id_usuario = isset($_SESSION["IDUSUARIO"]) ? $_SESSION["IDUSUARIO"] : false;
```

3) workingOn.php - In this file is where I make calls to DBConn in order to use those queries. If I do a call like this is just fine:

```
$res = $functionsDBConn->checkBracketGanador($id_torneo);
echo $res;
```

But, if I do it inside a function is where everything goes wrong

```
function test(){
    $res = $functionsDBConn->checkBracketGanador($id_torneo);
    return $res;
}
$a = test();
echo $a;
```

I keep getting this error:

**Fatal error: Call to a member function checkBracketGanador() on a non-object in .../someFolder/workingOn.php on line 67**

I've tried making public functions in classDBConn but didn't work

What I'm doing is calling the function outside the function and sending the result as a parameter to the other function but thats exactly what I want to avoid

Any help is appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to do with scope.

I assume you instantiate `$functionsDBConn = new DBConn();` outside the function at the same level as

```
$a = test();
```

If so you have 2 options

One:

```
function test(){
    global $functionsDBConn;
    $res = $functionsDBConn->checkBracketGanador($id_torneo);
    return $res;
}

$functionsDBConn = new DBConn();
$a = test();
echo $a;
```

Two:

```
function test(&$functionsDBConn){
    $res = $functionsDBConn->checkBracketGanador($id_torneo);
    return $res;
}
$functionsDBConn = new DBConn();
$a = test($functionsDBConn);
echo $a;
```

Basically you have to make the object you instantiated visible within the scope of your test() function by either telling the test() function it is available within the global scope `global $functionsDBConn;` or passing it into the function as a parameter.

You could also make checkBracketGanador() a static method but lets not get to complex all in a rush.

Answer (score 1):

Use `global` keyword inside the function. The variable inside the function will not call values outside its scope.

```
function test(){
    global $functionsDBConn;
    $res = $functionsDBConn->checkBracketGanador($id_torneo);
    return $res;
}
```